# Enable the SharePoint Server Publishing change the order of the links of my navigation bar

Tags: navigation, publishing, top-link-bar

I enabled the SharePoint Server Publishing feature and now it change my navigation bar, putting the selected site in the first order, but I don't want my navigation bar changes the order of the links. I can't edit the order because it does not appear when i click in the EDIT LINKS.

How can I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be :

1. add a script editor web part to your page
2. copy the following code into the script editor

*SharePoint 2013 code*

```
.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > a{ 
     display: none !important;
    }
 .ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > ul a{ 
    display: block !important;
    }
```

*SharePoint 2010 code*

```
    .s4-tn li.static > a{ 
 display: none !important; 
 } 
 .s4-tn li.static > ul a{ 
 display: block !important; 
 }
```

3. In Site Settings -- Navigation create a new link to the site
   [image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to site setting and navigation setting. In this page you have the option to rearrange links are per your requirements.

Comment: The link of the site where i am, it does not appear neither
in the navigation setting. It just say "current navigation" in the navigation setting but i cant move it. please be more specific.

Comment: Are you one the top level? Do you have enough permission to edit the links?

Comment: yes. i'm the site administrator.